# What tense should be used at sentence «Currently I work as engineer, but I also look for work as manager»?

Tags: present-tense

What tense should be used at this sentence? Now I use Present Simple, and at the one hand it seems to be right choice, because my work is not attached to a time, but at the other hand something this sentence seems wrong for me. So I need help with it.

Sentence is:

> Currently I work as engineer, but I also look for work as manager.

Comment: Your tense is fine, but your aspect is wrong. Beyond that, you’re lacking in articles.

Comment: Psst: in English language pronoun 'I" is always capitalized.

Comment: @tchrist can you correct it?

Comment: @brachkoff Tᴚoɯɐuo has done so in their answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to refer to an ongoing activity (as distinct from a normal or regular practice) use the continuous:

> I work as an engineer but I **am looking** for a job as a chef.
>
> The team wins most of its games but today they **are playing** poorly.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working as an engineer but I am looking for a job as a chef is also possible, if you expect (or hope) the engineering job to end soon.